# Count the sum of a column values in a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have a `table` where I should count if an user has reached a number of penalities like 3, so if the user reach or surpass 3 points, he's banned:

```
table_warnings
- id
- user_id
- warning
- warning_date

id    user_id     warning    warning_date
1     5478        1          2010-02-25 12:59:00
2     5478        1          2010-02-28 08:27:00
3     5478        2          2010-03-01 22:44:11
```

I've [started this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373759/manage-user-warnings), where the user KM helped me to fine a solution of a `SELECT` like this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(warning)
FROM table_warnings AS w
INNER JOIN table_users AS u
ON w.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE w.user_id = 5478 AND warning_date >= '2010-02-05 12:59:00'
HAVING COUNT(warning) >= 3
```

Can I find a way for a `SELECT` to retrieve how many penality points the user has got in the last 30 days?

Comment: Where is that `warn_penalty` field coming from?  You don't show it in your sample data.  Is it the same as `warning`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the column "warn_penalty".  May I assume it's the same as "warning"?  If so, simply change COUNT() to SUM().  With some additional fixing to eliminate the second table:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(warning)
FROM table_warnings 
WHERE  warning_date >= '2010-02-05 12:59:00'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(warning) >= 3
```

will return all users who are banned.

Alternatively, if you have a user_id and wish to know whether it is banned or not:

```
SELECT SUM(warning)
FROM table_warnings 
WHERE user_id = 5478 AND warning_date >= '2010-02-05 12:59:00'
```

and check the result.